# How do I condense the number of duplicates in a row, and count the attributes of another row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This may sound confusing but I'm struggling to figure out the best way to extract data from this table.

The table has 4 columns: `AppUserId`, `AppId`, `UserId`, `DownloadDate`.

There are 80+ entries for `AppUserId` and that same amount of entries for `AppId` (there are only 11 different `AppID`'s, they repeat according to the separate `AppUserId` entries).

However, I need to display the number of app users for each app Id. How should I type a SELECT query to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3):

> I need to display the number of app users for each app Id

Do you just need aggregation?

```
select AppId, count(*) from mytable group by AppId
```

Of, there are duplicate `(AppId, AppUserId)` and you want to count each tuple just once, use `count(distinct)`:

```
select AppId, count(distinct AppUserId) from mytable group by AppId
```

Comment: That worked! How would I then order the total number of users for each app in DESC?